# Can I find java methods using man page on linux terminal?

Tags: java, linux, javadoc

Question:
I realize that I can use man command on linux to see the class of linux commands. Am I able to look up java methods on the terminal instead of searching them on web browsers?

On the terminal, when I typed man java, I see a description of java running on terminal.

Do you usually look up java methods on the web?

Comment: You can probably download or install the jdk javadoc, either manually where you downloaded the jdk, or tell Maven or Gradle to also download a dependency's documentation. It's always just HTML though, so unless you use something like lynx as your browser, you won't be able to read it in the terminal.

Comment: I see. I will try downloading the jdk javadoc.